how to write web automation test with appium in flutter project?
this is my JavaScript code. I want run it in web with Appium. What should I do?
does Appium Flutter support web output?
const { remote } = require('webdriverio');
const { byValueKey } = require('appium-flutter-finder');

(async () => {
    const browser = await remote({
        logLevel: 'debug',
        port: 4723,
        capabilities: {
            'appium:platformName': 'Windows',
            'browserName': 'Chrome',
            'appium:app':'C:\\Users\\parisa.asghari\\AndroidStudioProjects\\appium_project\\web\\index.html',
           'appium:automationName': 'Chromium',
        },
    });

    const buttonFinder = byValueKey('Nbuttomn');
    await driver.elementClick(buttonFinder);
    await driver.elementClick(buttonFinder);
    await driver.elementClick(buttonFinder);
    await driver.elementClick(buttonFinder);
    await driver.elementClick(buttonFinder);

    const counterTextFinder = byValueKey('CounterText');
    const counterText = await driver.getElementText(counterTextFinder); // Get the counter's text
    if (counterText === '5') {
        console.log('PASS: Counter value is correct.');
    } else {
        console.log(`FAIL: Expected counter to be 5 but got ${counterText}`);
    }
    await driver.pause(1000);
})();

this is my cmd output
2024-08-20T06:53:43.042Z DEBUG webdriver: request failed due to response error: unknown error
2024-08-20T06:53:43.042Z ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 500 due to unknown error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find a driver for automationName 'flutter' and platformName 'Windows'. Have you installed a driver that `your text`supports those capabilities? Run 'appium driver list --installed' to see. (Lower-level error: Driver 'flutter' supports automationName 'Flutter', but Appium could not find support for platformName 'Windows'. Supported platformNames are: ["iOS","Android"])
2024-08-20T06:53:43.044Z ERROR webdriver: unknown error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find a driver for automationName 'flutter' and platformName 'Windows'. Have you installed a driver that supports those capabilities? Run 'appium driver list --installed' to see. (Lower-level error: Driver 'flutter' supports automationName 'Flutter', but Appium could not find support for platformName 'Windows'. Supported platformNames are: ["iOS","Android"])
    at getErrorFromResponseBody (file:///C:/appium-js/node_modules/webdriver/build/index.js:996:10)
    at FetchRequest._request (file:///C:/appium-js/node_modules/webdriver/build/index.js:1304:19)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async startWebDriverSession (file:///C:/appium-js/node_modules/webdriver/build/index.js:906:16)
    at async _WebDriver.newSession (file:///C:/appium-js/node_modules/webdriver/build/index.js:1502:41)
    at async remote (file:///C:/appium-js/node_modules/webdriverio/build/index.js:6964:20)
    at async C:\appium-js\test.js:6:21
file:///C:/appium-js/node_modules/webdriver/build/index.js:910
    throw new Error("Failed to create sessio`your text`n.\n" + message);
          ^``your text``
Error: Failed to create session.
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find a driver for automationName 'flutter' and platformName 'Windows'. Have you installed a driver that supports those capabilities? Run 'appium driver list --installed' to see. (Lower-level error: Driver 'flutter' supports automationName 'Flutter', but Appium could not find support for platformName 'Windows'. Supported platformNames are: ["iOS","Android"])
    at startWebDriverSession (file:///C:/appium-js/node_modules/webdriver/build/index.js:910:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async _WebDriver.newSession (file:///C:/appium-js/node_modules/webdriver/build/index.js:1502:41)
    at async remote (file:///C:/appium-js/node_modules/webdriverio/build/index.js:6964:20)
    at async C:\appium-js\test.js:6:21

